# Poission Summation Formula ProofWiki question

Tags: analysis, schwartz-space

Suppose that $f(x)$ is a Schwarz function, which is defined [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Schwarz_Function) to be a function

that satisfies for every $c \in \mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{N}, |f^{n}(x)| = o(|x|^c)$,

then in a proof of the Poisson Summation Formula [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Poisson_Summation_Formula), the author states that the function

$F(x)$ is $1$-periodic, where $F(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}f(x+n)$, with the reason given being absolute convergence.

I'm imagining if $F(x)$ is convergent, then $F(x+n)=F(x)$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ since we are simply
displacing the series values by $n$, but ultimately the series is the same.

I do not understand however why $F(x)$ converges at all. Why does the absolute convergence of the series
$\sum_{\mathbb{N}} |f(x+n)|$ imply the convergence of $F(x)$?

Comment: A Schwartz function (and all its derivatives) decay(s) faster than any polynomial, as mention in the begining of your post. Can you use that property (for $n=0$} to upper bound the series?

Comment: $f$ Schwartz implies that $F(x)=\sum_n f(x+n)$ converges absolutely and is continuous as well as its 2nd derivative from which $(2i\pi n)^2 c_n(F)$ is bounded ie. $F$'s Fourier series converges absolutely, to $F$.

Comment: You do know that every absolutely convergent series is conditionally convergent, don't you?

Comment: In the 2nd link, that is https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Poisson_Summation_Formula, is there typo in $F(x) = \sum_{k  \in \mathbb{Z}} {\hat f}(k) e^{i k x}$? Should it be $F(x) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}  {\hat f}(k) e^{2\pi i k x}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof of $F(x)$ converges:

since $|f(x)|=o(|x|^{-2})$ then $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}|f(x+n)|\leq\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}|x+n|^{-2}$ which is finite thanks to the Basel problem unless $x+n=0$, in which case just remove the finite term from the left hand side of the summation.
Since we know that an [absolutely convergent series of complex numbers is convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence#Proof_that_any_absolutely_convergent_series_of_complex_numbers_is_convergent), then $F(x)$ is convergent.

Comment: How does the convergence of $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}|x+n|^{-2}$ relate to the basel problem, which from my understanding is a proof that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+} \frac {1}{n^2} = \frac {\pi^2}{6}$ ? Thanks for the help!

Comment: After we omit $n_0,n_1$, the two closest $x+n$ to zero from the sum (i.e. the two terms that are less than $1$) we have that $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{n_0,n_1\}}|x+n|^{-2}\leq\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}}|n|^{-2}$ which is twice times $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$